# cloudflare-warp generates /etc/resolv.conf after i reboot my computer

Tags: internet, 22.04, wired

after i reboot, at /etc/resolv.conf i see this
[resolv.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S0jz.png)

Because of this, i cant use my Ethernet without warp connected. I'm fine with that, but how to fix that? How don't let warp change this file after i restart my computer?

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Latest stable warp.

Comment: @David, lol what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disconnect Warp Cloudflare, and then restart. It should generate a new /etc/resolv.conf file.

This behaviour should have been automatically enabled.

Comment: thank you, i'll try this out.

Comment: this ain't works that way you described, but it helped me. thx.